# Tree from an associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

There is an array:

```
let docs = [      
    { "_id":"1", parent:"_", "title":"one"},
    { "_id":"2", parent:"1", "title":"two"},
    { "_id":"4", parent:"_", "title":"title"},
    { "_id":"5", parent:"4", "title":"www"},
    {"_id":"_", "name":"root" },
];
```

I need to get out of it that's a tree:

```
{'_id':'_','name':'root','child':
    [
        {'_id':'1','parent':'_','title':'one','child':
            [
                {'_id':'2','parent':'1','title':'two','child':[]}
            ]
        },
        {'_id':'4','parent':'_','title':'title','child':
            [
                {'_id':'6','parent':'4','title':'vvv','child':[]}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But my code only works if the parent element is always higher on the list than the children, and I want to make that work universally.

This is code:

```
let node = {};
for (let doc of docs) {      
    doc.child = [];
    node[doc._id] = doc;

    if (typeof doc.parent === "undefined")
        tree = doc;
    else 
        node[doc.parent].child.push(doc);
}

console.log('tree->', JSON.stringify(tree));
```

code on codepen:
http://codepen.io/alex183/pen/OWvrPG?editors=0112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create recursive function using `reduce` method and basically check in each iteration of the parent property of current object is equal to passed `parent` param in function call.

```js
let docs = [      
    { "_id":"1", parent:"_", "title":"one"},
    { "_id":"2", parent:"1", "title":"two"},
    { "_id":"4", parent:"_", "title":"title"},
    { "_id":"5", parent:"4", "title":"www"},
    {"_id":"_", "name":"root" }
];

function makeTree(data, parent = undefined) {
  return data.reduce((r, e) => {
    // check if current e.parent is equal to parent
    if (e.parent === parent) {
      // make a copy of current e so we keep original as is
      const o = { ...e }
      // set value as output of recursive call to child prop
      o.child = makeTree(data, e._id)
      // push to accumulator
      r.push(o)
    }

    return r
  }, [])
}

console.log(makeTree(docs))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a proposal with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). It sorts the array in advance.

```js
var docs = [{ _id: "1", parent: "_", title: "one" }, { _id: "2", parent: "1", title: "two" }, { _id: "4", parent: "_", title: "title" }, { _id: "5", parent: "4", title: "www" }, { _id: "_", name: "root" }],
    order = { undefined: -2, _: -1 },
    tree = docs
        .sort((a, b) => (order[a.parent] || a.parent) - (order[b.parent] || b.parent) || a._id - b._id)
        .reduce(
            (m, a) => (
                m
                    .get(a.parent)
                    .push(Object.assign({}, a, { child: m.set(a._id, []).get(a._id) })),
                m
            ),
            new Map([[undefined, []]])
        )
        .get(undefined);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way is to use a sort function.

```
docs = docs.sort((a, b) => (a._id - b._id));
```

Comment: Do you mean to sort by parent instead of id?